# Prove that between $1001$ numbers we can pick $3$ such that $1$ is the sum of the other $2$

Tags: combinatorics

As much as basic this question might be for you, I find it hard to solve.

I need to prove that between $1001$ different numbers, smaller than $2000$, we can choose $3$ such that one of them would be the sum of the other two.

Comment: Are you saying: Prove that there must be at least one combination of three numbers chosen from 1001 non negative numbers less than 2000, that have the property that one is the sum of the other two?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the bad translation, english is not my native language.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: If for all $a,b $ in your set $a+b$ didn't belong to the set, then we would have a contradiction, as we have 1001 distinct numbers, each less than $2000$. By numbers I hope you mean natural numbers.